# c# report форматированный экспорт

Tags: c#, mysql, export, reportviewer, report

значит есть бд с 3 таблицами
[image: База даных]

на скринах, первые 2 дополнительные, 3-я основная.
требуется вывести в Report 3 и 1 таблицы относительно воторой...

[image: Подобие желаемой структуры]

и можно ли как то пропустить одну пустую строчку перед началом перечисления нового значения Ggrupa. или как то каждую групу записывать на отдельную страницу?

получить всех и закинуть в таблицу получается, и отсортировать по групе. а как сделать более структурированно, красиво?

Comment: вы описали задачу, но это ваша задача и за вас её решать никто не будет. Попробуйте сами её решить, и если будут конкретные вопросы по коду - спрашивайте.

Comment: Если бы я все задачи решал как вы говорите у меня бы за этот год было бы куда больше чем 2 вопроса. на данный момент уже все облазил и не могу найти решение... я не прошу решить задачу, хотя бы направление, идую, решения задачи.

Comment: Задавайте столько вопросов, сколько необходимо, в том проблем нет. Если хотите направления - это просто, начните с SQL запроса, в частности с инструкции JOIN

Comment: нет, sql запросы не как не помогают... тут нужны какие то определенные запросы в таблице отчетов, может фильтры.. есть LooKupSet... пытаюсь им манипулировать но он ошибки выдает, а какая ошибка не понятно, пишет **Код ошибки** как текст, а при написание самого запроса не каких ошибок синтаксических или еше каких либо не выдает. какие предложения на счет запросов в репортс, какие то нюансы есть которые не попались мне на глаза?

Comment: Все, более менее получилось... **код ошибки** выдает в связи с тем что LooKupSet возвращает множество обьектов,текста, который можно делить командой JOIN. А сама задача решилась простым групированием по нужному мне полю.